# What's an everyday or colloquial word for "trivia"?

Tags: single-word-requests

We all have lots of little things we have to remember that are what programmers often call Key Value Pairs in the format `key = value`.

e.g. `My shoe size is 11.` or `My wife's birthday is Feb. 29.`

EDIT: It's not just personal info though. The original impetus was for business, such as:
`Our third quarter sales goal is $375,000.`.

I can't use a programming term in everyday conversation with non-programmers. The closest I can come up with is trivia, but that sounds more suited for historical dates or random facts from Wikipedia.

Is there a normal everyday word for these individual details with the `key = value` format?

EDIT: I want people to see this word and quickly recognize what kind of information to put in this section with my assistance. So words requiring explanation or clarification won't work.

EDIT: @TylerN: `In this tool, you can save little [trivia] that you want to recall later.`

Comment: At least since the appearance of [Trivial Pursuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_Pursuit#:~:text=The%20game%20was%20created%20on,to%20create%20their%20own%20game.) board games / electronic pub games in the 80s, I would say that ***trivia*** is in fact the required "everyday" term, familiar to just about everyone today.

Comment: I think this depends a lot on context, for example, while shoe size might be considered as personal trivia but I think I'd be cautious using the same term for a date of birth (especially if it's on an official form).

Comment: Would **fact** work? I think it depends on what your example sentence would look like. If you're looking for a word to specifically imply the pair relationship, then I'd say no to **fact**, but if you're just looking for a word that works, then I think **fact** makes sense, because inherently there **has** to exist a `key` and a `value`, or even a `subject` and an `object`, if you will. Remember that sciences (computer science included) exist to solve real-world problems. A key-value-pair database exists to store those facts in a way that makes sense to a computer.

Comment: @Mithrandir If you would, please add an **example sentence** as when it comes to single-word-requests it is extremely helpful to those who answer. Helpful enough that it [is required](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests)

Comment: The word you use "details" is perfectly acceptable. A person's details is a recognised concept, and while it common refers to name, address, Date of birth etc, extending it to shoe size etc. should be intuitive.

Comment: Could you dispense with that format entirely e.g. "Save anything you want to recall later"?

Comment: @JeffUK, I suppose technically I could. I wanted to describe what types of information people should expect to save here though. As I said, I won't be there to clarify for the user so the words need to be precise so as to not need further clarification.